# ERROR: 'Error during cleanup of component' while running angular test cases

Tags: angular, testing

In my Angular app, when running test cases I suddenly got the below error in one of the components that were not even changed or modified with the current check-in into SVN.

> Error says:  HeadlessChrome  ERROR: 'Error during cleanup of
>   component'

I see my blogs that there is some problem in ngOnDestroy and unsubscribe
I am not able to figure out which component is likely failing.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Try destroying the component fixture in afterAll hooks and check whether it helps.

```
afterAll(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
```

Comment: it didn't help.